# (EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/app/node_modules/.cache) How can I create a docker-compose file to make node_modules a non-root folder?

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, create-react-app

I'm trying to dockerize a simple create-react-app project. (**Is the initial project after running `npx create-react-app test`, no files were changed**).

The problem seems to be that in newer versions of [React](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/9977), they moved the annoying `.eslintcache` from the root folder to `/node_modules/.cache`, causing problems when the container is trying to run the application via `docker-compose`.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN chown -R node.node /usr/app/node_modules

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3'
services: 
  test:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - /usr/app/node_modules
      - .:/usr/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

The container is logging this error message:

```
test_1   | Failed to compile.
test_1   | 
test_1   | EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/app/node_modules/.cache
```

As you can notice, I tried to set the `node_modules` folder owner to the node user (the default user for `node:alpine`), but it is not working; exploring the container, you can see that the `node_modules` folder is still owned by `root`:

```
drwxrwxr-x    5 node     node          4096 Apr 14 07:04 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Apr 14 07:08 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           310 Apr 14 06:56 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           192 Apr 14 07:30 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node          3369 Apr 14 06:56 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 1061 root     root         36864 Apr 14 07:12 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node        692936 Apr 14 06:56 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           808 Apr 14 06:56 package.json
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Apr 14 06:56 public
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Apr 14 06:56 src
```

I also tried to create the folder `RUN mkdir -p /usr/app` and use `USER node` but that end up in an issue where npm wasn't able to create the `node_modules` folder.

Is there any workaround where either `.eslintcache` is disabled or `node_modules` is owned by the `node` user?

### Update

Apparently, this is occurring because I'm using **Ubuntu** and docker mounts volumes as root on Linux systems.

Comment: I'd delete the `volumes:` so that you're actually running the code built into the image.  That also avoids the sorts of permission problems you're describing, and means changes to your `package.json` file will be honored.  You can directly run `node` without Docker to do development, and to run developer-only tools like `eslint`.

Comment: I wondered if I can do this since I want a complete dockerized development environment; I have two other services (back and mongo) in the `docker-compose`. Plus, it seems started to happen after the last CRA release, that configuration that I posted worked in previous versions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Adding this line just after `RUN npm install` in your Dockerfile would solve the issue:

```
RUN mkdir -p node_modules/.cache && chmod -R 777 node_modules/.cache
```

Final Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

RUN mkdir node_modules/.cache && chmod -R 777 node_modules/.cache

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Then you don't need to copy the `node_modules` folder from your local dir to the container. You can safely bookmark it.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the corresponding /usr/app/node_modules volume is removed. Otherwise, after changing the dockerfile, the docker compose command will use the same volume as before without this change in permissions, and it will keep failing

Answer (score 5):

**If you have a local node_modules folder delete it before running docker or docker-compose**

Because there might have been another situation which causes
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/app/node_modules/.cache

This might be a case that you previously run this react-app with local node_modules file then deleted the file to use the container node_module.

So after deleting the whole folder it still recreates the folder and keeps a .cache file in it which is generally not visible.

So when you bookmark all file using `".:/usr/app" in docker-compose.yml or
-v "$(pwd):/usr/app" it tries to bookmark that cache file stored in that local_node modules repo and causes all the fuss.

Comment: In my case I forgot to add the node_modules to the .dockerignore file, so even though I was creating a user and telling docker to use that user to install the packages, later the COPY command was overriding the node_modules in the container with the local one.

Answer (score 4):

I've just stumbled across the same issue. If you're wondering how I dealt with it I simply added two lines before the last line. It worked like a charm.

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install --silent

COPY . .

RUN chown -R node /app/node_modules

USER node

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: This is what got it to work on windows! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a long-standing issue with NPM changing its process's UID which is now fixed NPM 9.

Specifically, it is described in [this NPM RFC comment](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/546#issuecomment-1125479739):

> Docker volume mounts use the UID:GID of the host machine. The changes
> npm has made to infer the execution user from the UID:GID effectively
> break docker setups where the host users UID:GID does not match the
> node user on the container. Setting UID:GID in a .env file for each
> developer in our application is cumbersome and overall ridiculous.
> Stop trying to infer best security practices when it comes to running
> scripts, your job is to be a package manager

This fix is called out prominently in [the v9.0.0 changelog announcement](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-24-npm-v9-0-0-released/#about-this-release).

Related changes in NPM tracker:

- https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v9.1.2/CHANGELOG.md#900-pre6-2022-10-19
- https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/546
- https://github.com/npm/statusboard/issues/540
- https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/5703
- https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/5704

Answer (score 1):

Well, It is clearly showing that you don't have read, write and execute permission in your node modules folder and you will probably see a lock icon appearing on the node module folder.

**FOR UBUNTU any version**

```
sudo chmod a+rwx <path>/your-project-folder/node_modules
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
sudo chmod a+rwx Desktop/react-app/node_modules
```

*explanation*

- chmod - to change permission
- a - all
- rwx - read, write and execute

Answer (score 1):

To fix that issue in KUBERNETES, you have to mount an empty dir volume with the path directory `/app/.next/cache`. Check the example.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deploy
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: my-label
    spec:
      containers:
        image: ghcr.io/myimage
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: my-site
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/.next/cache
          name: cache
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: cache
```

Answer (score 1):

In the DOCKER-COMPOSE File remove the volumes where you trying to exculde node_modules.
It will work

Answer (score 1):

Well Its clearly shown you don't have access in node modules in your docker container.I tried a lot, but below given form works for me.

> RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

> RUN chmod +rwx /usr/src/app

WORKDIR  /usr/src/app

first give READ WRITE EDIT permission via above command
for your work-directory file, then it will working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came out with was installing the `node_modues` locally and then modify the `Dockerfile` to copy everything into the container and use that as a volume instead of installing and bookmarking `node_modules` during the build process. I know it's not the best approach to this problem, but it's an easy solution for something I've been trying to solve for days.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3'
services: 
  test:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Move 'USER node' higher**

I was only using Docker (no docker-compose) and the solution was to move `USER node` to before `COPY package*...`

Answer (score 0):

**In Linux,**
**You have to give read and write permissions to your React App.**

```
sudo chmod a+rwx <path>/your-project-folder/node_modules
```

**Example**

```
sudo chmod a+rwx my-app/node_modules
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

In Mac you can run **sudo chown -R $(whoami)** path

Example: sudo chown -R $(whoami) react-survey-app/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

The thing is, I used `vue create` inside /tmp, and then moved the content of the created folder inside my volume.

Which apparently npm is not too fond of.

So I removed `node_modules`, and recreated it using `npm install`, now it works like a charm.